# Extracting data from a script by Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have something like that:

```
(async () => {
    await import("https://s-gr.cdngr.pl/assets/gratka/v0.40.7/dist/js/Map.js");

    Map.init('#item-map', {
      gratkaMapsUrl: 'https://map.api.gratka.it',
      assetsUrl: 'https://s-gr.cdngr.pl/assets/gratka/v0.40.7/dist/',
      locationApiHost: 'https://locations.api.gratka.it/locations/v1',
      apiUrl: 'https://gratka.api.gratka.it/gratka/v2',
      eventType: 'click',
      statisticsType: 'show_map',
      locationParams: {"lokalizacja_ulica":"aleja Marsz. J\u00f3zefa Pi\u0142sudskiego","lokalizacja_szerokosc-geograficzna-y":52.231069627971,"lokalizacja_region":"mazowieckie","lokalizacja_powiat":"Warszawa","lokalizacja_miejscowosc":"Warszawa","lokalizacja_kraj":"Polska","lokalizacja_gmina":"Warszawa","lokalizacja_dlugosc-geograficzna-x":21.2497334550424},
      offersId: [18702037]
    });
  })();
```

Im looking for a method to extract these params: "lokalizacja_ulica", "lokalizacja_szerokosc-geograficzna-y" and "lokalizacja_dlugosc-geograficzna-x". Any ideas? I'm python newbie :<

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract information from js with bs4 afaik. You can use regex though.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(<html text>)
script = soup.find('script').string
match = re.search(r'(?<=locationParams: ).+(?=,\n)', script, re.M).group(0)
data = json.loads(match)
```

(?<=locationParams: ).+(?=,\n) pattern looks for anything that has a "locationParams: " before and a curly bracket followed by a newline character after it. Then you can pass that string into json.loads() which turns it into a python dictionary.